# Login or Register Button Not Working In Angular/Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import{AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  user={
    email :'',
    password :''
  };

  public ngFireAuth:AngularFireAuth;

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async login()
  {
    const user=await this.ngFireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email,this.user.password);
    console.log(user);
    if(user.user.email)
    {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
    else{
      alert('Login Failed!');
    }
  }

  async register()
  {
    const user=await this.ngFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email,this.user.password);
    console.log(user);
    if(user.user.email)
    {
      alert('Registration sucessfull!');
    }
    else{
      alert('Registration Failed!');
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is from my login.page.ts

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input [(ngModule)]="user.email" placeholder="Enter Email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input [(ngModule)]="user.password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-button (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
      <ion-button expand="block" color="secondary" (click)="register()">Register</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

The above code is from my login.page.html

I am not getting any response when I click the register or login button. I have implemented Google Firebase for authentication of the user but after entering the email and password, the user doesn't get register nor can login. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this code from my firebase project. Might help you.

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
  constructor(
    private _afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) { }  

  /**
   * Login to firebase with method email/password
   */
  async signInWithEmailAndPassword() : Promise<void>{
    await this._afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.inputEmail, this.inputPassword)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Also insure in your app module.

```html
const angularFirebase = [
  AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
  AngularFireAuthModule,
];
```

insert into imports array